# getFileAsync causing Excel to crash

Tags: excel, office-js

I'm building an office-js add-in for Excel. I need to upload the current workbook to a back end server.  I've implemented an example from the Micrsoft Documentation,  which seems to work fine the first time I call it, but on subsequent calls, it causes Excel to crash.  I'm using Excel 365 version 1812 (build 11126.20132)

Here is the link to the example in the MS docs: 
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/office/office.document

There are many examples on this page, to find the one I'm working from search for "The following example gets the document in Office Open XML"  I've included the example below for ease of reference.

The code just get's the current file and dumps the characters to the console's log.  It works fine the first but crashes Excel the second time--after it has shown the length of FileContent.

```js
export function getDocumentAsCompressed() {
    Office.context.document.getFileAsync(Office.FileType.Compressed, { sliceSize: 65536 /*64 KB*/ },
        function (result) {
            if (result.status == "succeeded") {
                // If the getFileAsync call succeeded, then
                // result.value will return a valid File Object.
                var myFile = result.value;
                var sliceCount = myFile.sliceCount;
                var slicesReceived = 0, gotAllSlices = true, docdataSlices = [];
                console.log("File size:" + myFile.size + " #Slices: " + sliceCount);

                // Get the file slices.
                getSliceAsync(myFile, 0, sliceCount, gotAllSlices, docdataSlices, slicesReceived);
            }else {
                console.log("Error:", result.error.message);
            }
    });
}

function getSliceAsync(file, nextSlice, sliceCount, gotAllSlices, docdataSlices, slicesReceived) {
    file.getSliceAsync(nextSlice, function (sliceResult) {
        if (sliceResult.status == "succeeded") {
            if (!gotAllSlices) { // Failed to get all slices, no need to continue.
                return;
            }

            // Got one slice, store it in a temporary array.
            // (Or you can do something else, such as
            // send it to a third-party server.)
//            console.log("file part",sliceResult.value.data)
            docdataSlices[sliceResult.value.index] = sliceResult.value.data;
            if (++slicesReceived == sliceCount) {
              // All slices have been received.
              file.closeAsync();
              onGotAllSlices(docdataSlices);
            }
            else {
                getSliceAsync(file, ++nextSlice, sliceCount, gotAllSlices, docdataSlices, slicesReceived);
            }
        }
            else {
                gotAllSlices = false;
                file.closeAsync();
                console.log("getSliceAsync Error:", sliceResult.error.message);
            }
    });
}

function onGotAllSlices(docdataSlices) {
    var docdata = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < docdataSlices.length; i++) {
        docdata = docdata.concat(docdataSlices[i]);
    }

    var fileContent = new String();
    for (var j = 0; j < docdata.length; j++) {
        fileContent += String.fromCharCode(docdata[j]);
    }

   console.log("fileContent.length",fileContent.length)

    // Now all the file content is stored in 'fileContent' variable,
    // you can do something with it, such as print, fax...
}
```

Here is the result

```js
File size:21489 #Slices: 1
fileContent.length 21489
```

Original example from Microsoft documentation (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/office/office.document)

```js
// The following example gets the document in Office Open XML ("compressed") format in 65536 bytes (64 KB) slices.
// Note: The implementation of app.showNotification in this example is from the Visual Studio template for Office Add-ins.
function getDocumentAsCompressed() {
    Office.context.document.getFileAsync(Office.FileType.Compressed, { sliceSize: 65536 /*64 KB*/ }, 
        function (result) {
            if (result.status == "succeeded") {
            // If the getFileAsync call succeeded, then
            // result.value will return a valid File Object.
            var myFile = result.value;
            var sliceCount = myFile.sliceCount;
            var slicesReceived = 0, gotAllSlices = true, docdataSlices = [];
            app.showNotification("File size:" + myFile.size + " #Slices: " + sliceCount);

            // Get the file slices.
            getSliceAsync(myFile, 0, sliceCount, gotAllSlices, docdataSlices, slicesReceived);
            }
            else {
            app.showNotification("Error:", result.error.message);
            }
    });
}

function getSliceAsync(file, nextSlice, sliceCount, gotAllSlices, docdataSlices, slicesReceived) {
    file.getSliceAsync(nextSlice, function (sliceResult) {
        if (sliceResult.status == "succeeded") {
            if (!gotAllSlices) { // Failed to get all slices, no need to continue.
                return;
            }

            // Got one slice, store it in a temporary array.
            // (Or you can do something else, such as
            // send it to a third-party server.)
            docdataSlices[sliceResult.value.index] = sliceResult.value.data;
            if (++slicesReceived == sliceCount) {
              // All slices have been received.
              file.closeAsync();
              onGotAllSlices(docdataSlices);
            }
            else {
                getSliceAsync(file, ++nextSlice, sliceCount, gotAllSlices, docdataSlices, slicesReceived);
            }
        }
            else {
                gotAllSlices = false;
                file.closeAsync();
                app.showNotification("getSliceAsync Error:", sliceResult.error.message);
            }
    });
}

function onGotAllSlices(docdataSlices) {
    var docdata = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < docdataSlices.length; i++) {
        docdata = docdata.concat(docdataSlices[i]);
    }

    var fileContent = new String();
    for (var j = 0; j < docdata.length; j++) {
        fileContent += String.fromCharCode(docdata[j]);
    }

    // Now all the file content is stored in 'fileContent' variable,
    // you can do something with it, such as print, fax...
}

// The following example gets the document in PDF format.
Office.context.document.getFileAsync(Office.FileType.Pdf,
    function(result) {
        if (result.status == "succeeded") {
            var myFile = result.value;
            var sliceCount = myFile.sliceCount;
            app.showNotification("File size:" + myFile.size + " #Slices: " + sliceCount);
            // Now, you can call getSliceAsync to download the files,
            // as described in the previous code segment (compressed format).

            myFile.closeAsync();
        }
        else {
            app.showNotification("Error:", result.error.message);
        }
}
);
```

Comment: I would love to help, but I do not know how to go forward. I presume that there are no error messages and logs from the Event Viewer probably do not provide any valuable information. This makes it more of a guessing game, my advice would be to post this on the [issue page](https://github.com/OfficeDev/office-js/issues) for office.js.

Comment: Flous: Thanks for taking a look and thanks for the recommendation.  You are right, no error messages.  I'm not sure just what the Event viewer is, but I'll track it down and see if anything useful is there.

Answer (score 0):

Since you're using Excel, have you tried the [CreateWorkbork API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/excel/excel-add-ins-workbooks?view=office-js#create-a-workbook)? Might be a good workaround if the Document API has a bug, like Xuanzhou indicated earlier.

[Here's a CreateDocument snippet](https://github.com/OfficeDev/office-js-snippets/blob/master/samples/excel/50-workbook/create-workbook.yaml) that you can load into [Script Lab](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/garage/profiles/script-lab/). It shows how to create a Workbook copy based on an existing file.

Hope all that is helpful.

Answer (score -2):

We already have a fix for it now. But the fix still need some time to go to production. Please try it several days later and let me know if the issue still exists. Thanks.

Comment: Could you please share the fix. I am facing the same issue.